# Altering innerText in an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, dom, coffeescript

This seems to me like it should be straight-forward, but I think I'm misunderstanding the order of operations here. The documentation is a bit tough for me to digest and the answers I've found here have led me closer to an answer but not quite far enough.

I'm trying to place a scope variable (containing a string) onto the DOM using a directive and I want to manipulate that text and eventually create a "Read More" text truncation function.

HTML snippet:

`<read-more>{{ commentary }}</read-more>`

Angular/Coffeescript:

```
  app.directive('readMore', [ ->
    restrict: 'E'
    scope: false
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      console.log(element[0])
      element[0].innerText = element[0].innerText.substring(0, 125) + "..."
  ])
```

The text from that variable gets read into the DOM, and console logs the element as `<read-more ng-class="ng-binding">` and the `{{ commentary }}` string is printed in the console between the tags, however, my function doesn't manipulate it.

I know it's the correct element (and index), but for some reason innerText and innerHTML don't affect what is on the DOM.

If I change the return line in the `link` function to:

```
element[0].innerText = "Foo"
```

I get nothing between the `<read-more>` tags in the console and, naturally, the DOM now has no content in  there.

What am I missing about how `link` deals with this element on the DOM?

Comment: I think you need to read up about transclusion

Comment: I tried reading the docs on it; would be more than happy to see a better explanation as an answer to this question!

Comment: I don't use transclusion and would just pass the variable in as an attribute instead `<read-more usethis='commentary'></read-more>`. If you set up the code on SO or plnkr I'm happy to work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides a wrapper for the element using jQuery (if available) or jQLite, so use the `html` or `text` function:

```
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  commentString = element.html() ## alternatively use element.text()
```

Note, however, that both the `text` and `html` functions will return the unevaluated string `{{ commentary }}` rather than whatever string value the `commentary` variable holds.

To get around this, simply address `commentary` using the `scope` argument passed to the directive's `link` function.

```
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  commentString = scope.commentary

  ...  ## perform string manipulation here

  element.text(newCommentString)
```

This will set the element text to whatever string you pass to it. As for updating the text: if something like "read more" is clicked, have an event handler ready (still inside of `link:`, like so:

```
element.on('click', ->
  element.text(commentString) ## the full commentary string from above
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that element you are dealing here is not the JS element you are dealing for example in a standard jQuery function. This is [angularjs element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), Instead of DOM manypulation, I would rather create a directive that sets the model of the "Read More" element, and also hides the entire text that needs to be displayed after click on it. But do that only via angularjs ng-model directive, not by DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need DOM for angular.

Here show you a few ways to bind content:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OSWIy0?p=preview

Use this

```
link: function($scope) {
    $scope.otherText = 'Here more text. For example, this maybe come from http-stream.';
}
```

instead this:

```
element[0].innerText = element[0].innerText.substring(0, 125) + "..."
```

Good luck. :-)

Comment: Yes, addressing the value from the scope argument is the easier route for sure.